# How to add combined constraint on MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a simple library management application where issued books data is captured in a table called 'transaction'. The structure of this table is as below where date_of_return can be null if the book is yet not returned by the member. Once the book is returned to library the date_of_return will be set to some datetime value and i.e. not null.

Since a book can be issued to only to one member at a time we should find atmost one row for a book_id where the date_of_return is null. No two rows for a given book_id with date_of_return is not null. How to specify this as a constraint? Because this seems to be of type unique constraint which is complex.

Is writing trigger the only way to solve this problem?

```
mysql> describe transaction;

+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| id             | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| book_id        | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |

| member_id      | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |

| date_of_issue  | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

| date_of_return | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: I am no clear on what transaction holds. Do you create a new transaction every time a book is issued? And I'm not clear what the problem is do you want to refuse a return if the previous issue was not returned, or do you want to refuse an issue if the last transaction is not marked as returned for a book?

Comment: @P.Salmon-for refusing an issue of book which is not returned yet. Everytime a book is issued a new row is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create unqiue constraint for (book_id, date__of_return) so that if the book is not yet returned, no one can have the book. suppose that your table has this record

```
book_id  ... . date_of_return
   1               null
```

then there won't be any other record with same `book_id` and `date_of_Return`

```
ALTER TABLE transactions
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_transactions_book UNIQUE (book_id,date_of_return);
```

and since your `date_of_Return` is datetime, you wont have problem when the book is issued and returned multiple times in same day.

Comment: Though the alter table sql is executed successfully and a unique constraint is added on the table, this constraint does not consider null value in date_of_return to be unique. It only applicable if there is some value in date_of_return column. I verified on MySQL 8.0.13 community server. I accepted the answer immediately after running the SQL which did not return any error/warning.

Comment: can you consider to assign return_date 01-01-2999 ?  I have different ideas as well but this would solve your issue. I am sorry for misleading you

Comment: cannot assign something like 01-01-2999 to return_date, it will lead to inconsistency, business will not accept it as they already specified if return_date having some value means the book is returned or else return_date should be null

Comment: You can add generated column with case statement if the date is 01.01.2999 you can show it null. And use that generated column